# Replace every single Character with a random Letter from a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, random, replace

```
Replace_Character = input("Enter ! here: ")
Replace_Character = Replace_Character.replace("!",random.choice(Letters))
```

When I run this, it does replace the ! with a random Letter from the list but the Letters are all the same. How can I make it so every ! get another Letter?

Comment: please add your full code.

Comment: The `replace` function replaces all instances of the first argument with the second argument. You will have to use a different way than just a one liner to be able to change each instance with a different letter.

Answer (score 1):

Here I'm using a generator expression and assuming you want to sample randomly with replacement:

```
>>> import string
>>> import random
>>> letters = string.ascii_lowercase
>>> print(letters)
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
>>> test = '!A!B!!'
>>> ''.join(random.choice(letters) if c == '!' else c for c in test)
'uAqBtq'
>>> ''.join(random.choice(letters) if c == '!' else c for c in test)
'xApBfo'
```

Comment: I tried it but it somehow does not work. Thank you for your help though.

Comment: Could you explain what "does not work"? This does exactly what you asked for.

Answer (score 0):

Chris's solution works, I want to provide some context on why yours doesn't.

```
Replace_Character = Replace_Character.replace("!",random.choice(Letters))
```

To evaluate this, Python needs to figure out what arguments to call str.replace() with. It knows the first argument is `"!"`, but it needs to evaluate the second one. So it first executes `random.choice(Letters)`. Let's say it gets the letter `q`. Then, it calls Replace_Character.replace("!", "q"). You can see how that's going to set it to the same character every time.

One-line string generator tricks are neat, but might be overwhelming or hard to read. Here's an equivalent of what Chris' answer does, written with a plain for loop.

```
new_string = ""
for character in old_string:
    if (character == "!"):
        # generate a random letter to replace the ! with
        new_string += random.choice(Letters)
    else:
        # copy the old text, unmodified
        new_string += character
```

Comment: (strings in Python are immutable, which means this would probably have much worse performance than a solution like Chris', but I think it provides the most clarity on what's going on, and that seems important here)